# How to use more CPU cores in SpaceClaim?

Tags: cad, ansys

This is a more technical rather than professional question. I have a hyper-threaded quad core CPU. While building models in SpaceClaim I noticed that it only uses one logical core. A single core will be on a very high usage percentage while the others are nearly idle. How can I set SpaceClaim to use more cores and make better benefit of the CPU?

Comment: I don't have the specific answer, but I don't think CAD modeling is multi-threaded. Since there is a dependency/hierarchy it's a singular thread. On the other hand, Something like image rendering or FEA can take advantage of multiple cores as the problems can be logically split, computed and results joined, your cad software may have specific options for these features.

Comment: Good answers already, but a better fit on Computing or Hardware stacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software must be programmed specifically to use multiple cores. There is nothing restricting SpaceClaim or any other CAD software from being programmed this way, but it is currently more complex/expensive to program and there is no immediate incentive for companies to work this direction. Their software is already very expensive, so their customers don't mind buying a faster computer every year. Customers won't demand multi threading support until the price of software drops below the price of new computers.

Here is an (unfortunately old 2007) list I copied from [toms hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/243332-28-programs-cores-quad-core-chip). It helps paint the picture of how few programs are multi threaded. The main thing a multiple core processor buys you is the ability to run different programs at 100% simultaneously.

> - 3D Studio MAX using Mental Ray Renderer (>99 % of 4 cores)
> - Adobe Premiere Elements v3.0.2 (52 - 85 % of 4 cores depending on source type, filters, etc.)
> - AutoGK v2.40 (30 - 53 % of 4 cores depending on source type, filters, etc.)
> - Cinema 4d Rendering (>99 % of 4 cores)
> - Dr. DivX v2.0.0 (47 - 65 % of 4 cores depending on source type, filters, etc.)
> - DVDShrink v3.2 (~90 % of 4 cores)
> - Lightwave 3D (>99 % of 4 cores)
> - Nero Suite 7.x (>90 % of 4 cores when encoding)
> - Noise Ninja v2.13 (~80 % of 4 cores when doing the noise reduction on an image)
> - Sony Vegas 7.0e (83 - 100 % of 4 cores depending on source type, filters, etc.)
> - TMPG XPress v4.2.3.193 (65 - 100 % of 4 cores depending on source type, filters, etc.)
> - Winrar v3.70   (~85 - 90 % of 4 cores on benchmark; ~75% in practice)
> - x264 v0.55.663 (>99 % of 4 cores when doing the 2nd pass of a 2 pass encode)